# Issues in Camera Intent and image passing

Tags: java, android, android-camera-intent

I have an activity in which i open camera in surface view and capture a image.The captured is shown on the next activity of the image view.but result activity shows a white screen data not passing into result activity Please tell me the code how i pass image to next activity?

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 

 {

 int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void takePicture(View v) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this,Result.class);
            i.putExtra("filepath",1);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Result Activity

```
 public class Result extends Activity


 {


 ImageView iv;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image);
    iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.getParcelable("filepath");
    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this `i.putExtra("filepath",yourfilepath);`
and get it in next Activity..

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
String filepath=intent.getStringExtra("filepath");
```

Decode it in bitmap..

```
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File image = new File(sd+filePath, imageName);
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(),bmOptions);
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,parent.getWidth(),parent.getHeight(),true);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Additionally you can get imagepath here..
In `onActivityResult(...){`

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);

    // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
    String finalpath =getRealPathFromURI(tempUri)
   //now you can putextra here
```

Here is the methods.

```
    public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null); 
    cursor.moveToFirst(); 
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
    return cursor.getString(idx); 
}
```